# Mathematical Definition of Point Source

Tags: definition, singularity

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_source#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20point%20source,in%20physics%20and%20other%20fields) describes a mathematical definition of a point source as "a singularity from which flux or flow is emanating".

The usual definition in Physics describes it just as a source whose dimensions are negligible in comparison to another variable you're relating it to, which leads to well-behaved phenomena such as isotropic emission.

Well, if there's something I wouldn't expect from a singularity, that's well-behaving. Given that, how does that math definition of point source makes sense? How to phenomenologically relate it, lucidly, it with physics?

Comment: A point in mathematics is just a location in space. A point source in physics is one in which only its location is relevant to the problem being described. That is consistent with your second paragraph.

Comment: To complement John's comment, the term _singularity_ doesn't necessarily signify that some quantity is infinite. Particularly, a zero of a smooth vector field is a _singularity_ in the sense here. The term gets applied because the direction of the field can change discontinuously, but in the sense of calculus a "singularity" may be perfectly well-behaved.

Comment: More musings on zero and infinity: Anything that's infinitely small (such as your point source of zero size) or infinitely large (such as magnitude of a field at zero distance) is a *mathematical idealization*. Physical quantities can be very small or very large, but not *infinitely* so! But these idealizations are convenient. So we use them as approximations of the actual quantities. Hence, a point source is a good approximation of a very, very small source.